# Missing 'New' button in data factory connections page in Azure Purview

Tags: azure-purview

I am trying to connect data factories to my Azure purview account. But I can't see the 'New' button on my data factory connections page. All I see is the Refresh button. Can someone please help me understand what am I missing?

I have the Contributor, Reader, Purview Data Curator & Purview Data Source Administrator Roles assigned to my user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's odd, you should be able to follow the screenshots here.

1. To navigate to Purview Studio [Navigate to Purview Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62ZW6.png)
2. To Add your Data Factory [Add your data factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RDNR.png)

It may be your access to your data factory that is blocking you. If you could post a screenshot of the Role based Access you have to Data Factory it would help, as well as your purview studio.

I have the same roles as you for Purview, except that I'm also an owner, so you should be good from a Purview perspective.

Comment: Hmmm is it not strange that even as a contributor you cannot add a Data Factory connection? But are you able to add all of the other connections? That doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 0):

In order to add or remove the Data Factory connections in the Azure Purview portal, you need to be assigned any one of the Purview roles:

- Owner User
- Access Administrator

Besides, it requires the users to be the data factory’s “**Owner**”, or “**Contributor**”.

**Follow the steps below to connect an existing Data Factory accounts to your Purview Data Catalog.**

1. Select **Management Center** on the left navigation pane.
2. Under **External connections**, select **Data Factory** connection.
3. On the **Data Factory connection** page, select **New**.
4. Select your **Data Factory account** from the list and select **OK**. You can also filter by subscription name to limit your list.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Reference:** [How to connect Azure Data Factory and Azure Purview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/how-to-link-azure-data-factory).